# proof of associativity of natural number with inductive principle with agda

Tags: proof-verification, homotopy-type-theory

Given the inductive principle of natural number which is able to prove any P(n) of n:N:

```
data ℕ : Set where
  z : ℕ
  s : ℕ → ℕ

nind : {C : ℕ -> Set} -> C z -> ((n : ℕ) -> C n -> C (s n) ) -> ((n : ℕ)-> C n)
nind c0 cs z = c0
nind c0 cs (s n) = cs n (nind c0 cs n)
```

and some library function from hott-agda to prove that if m==n then suc m==suc n

```
ap : ∀ {i j} {A : Type i} {B : Type j} (f : A → B) {x y : A}
  → (x == y → f x == f y)
ap f idp = idp
```

I was able to prove that

```
runitN : (m : ℕ)-> (m + z ) == m
runitN  = nind idp (\ _ cn -> ap s cn) -- idp here is refl,and
```

but failed to prove

```
+assoc : (a b c : ℕ) -> ((a + b) + c ) == (a + (b + c))
+assoc  = nind idp (\ n p -> (\ b c -> ap s (p  b c)))
```

I know there is no doubt that the zero case is  idp(refl),and the type of p is ℕ->ℕ-> C(n),so i just wrap p with a lambda and apply s to it,and the return type should be ℕ->ℕ-> C(n)

But agda says :

```
(_a_46 == _a_46) !=< ((b c : ℕ) → ((z + b) + c) == (z + (b + c)))
of type Set
when checking that the expression idp has type
(b c : ℕ) → ((z + b) + c) == (z + (b + c))
```

How to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

After consulting a professor,I found the error is located at the base case,the base case is not merely idp,it should be given parameters according the type of +assoc,that is:

```
+assoc : (a b c : ℕ) -> ((a + b) + c ) == (a + (b + c))
+assoc  = nind (\_ _ -> idp ) (\ n p -> (\ b c -> ap s (p b c)))
```